# ipython reload ipython_config.py

Tags: ipython

In ipython, I have the `ipython_config.py`

when I make changes in this file, how I can reload ipython ? (without restart ipython)

for example for change the prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't - that file is read when you start IPython. You can change any configured value while IPython is running:

```
%config PromptManager.in_template = "\\#>>>"
```

That won't be stored in the config file, though.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me `%config TerminalInteractiveShell.editor = 'emacs'`